# sed doesn't work from within bash script

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I've searched for hours looking for the answer to this question which seems frustratingly simple...

I have a bash script which I've simplified to find the line that's stopping it from working and am left with:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
sed -i -e "s/<link>/\n/g" /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rss.tmp
```

If I run this script, nothing happens to the file rss.tmp - but if I call this exact same sed command from the terminal, it makes all the replacements as expected.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I assume bash is your interactive shell, the PATH is the same (so you are running the same `sed`), and so on?  This script works fine for me...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to check if bash is my interactive shell or if the PATH is the same... should probably admit that this is my first attempt at an sh script so very new to all this

Comment: `echo $SHELL` should tell you what your interactive shell is.  If it is bash, try running `type -a sed` both in the interactive shell and in your script to see if they are the same.  (Or just use `/bin/sed` instead of `sed` to avoid searching the PATH.)  As I said, your script works fine for me, so this is really grasping at straws...

Comment: echo $SHELL gives the result /bin/sh.  type -a sed gives /bin/sed from the terminal but adding this to the script it doesn't output anything...

Comment: Are you sure you are actually running the script?  (What happens if you add `echo HELLO` to it, for instance?)

Comment: also, not sure if it helps at all, but adding echo $PATH to the script gives this output - /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin

Comment: `type` is a bash built-in function; it ought to output _something_.  What kind of system is this?  Maybe try `#!/bin/sh` to definitely use the same shell as your interactive session?  Something is very, very strange here...

Comment: Tried creating a new script just containing the below but still no output:`#!/bin/sh
#
type -a sed
`

Comment: The system is a NAS device and it's running "snakeos" - http://www.dealextreme.com/p/standalone-bittorrent-bt-client-usb-nas-ftp-samba-printer-upnp-sharing-network-lan-server-26320

Comment: Have you tried using `#!/bin/sh` for the shell and `/bin/sed ...` instead of `sed ...` in the script?

Comment: yes, tried replacing `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/sh` and also tried replacing `sed` with `/bin/sed` but get the same result that the `sed` doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: `Tried creating a new script ... but still no output` You shouldn't expect any output. `sed -i` changes the file in place. I don't know why Nemo is suggesting to investigate the kind of shell, since the command does not contain some bash specialities.

Comment: One last thought is to use `#!/bin/sh -x` or `#!/bin/bash -x` to tell the shell to print the characters it is executing...  Hey, I just had an idea.  Is it possible that you are confusing carriage returns and newlines, such that the "#" starting the comment is also consuming your command?

Comment: I meant "print the _commands_ it is executing".  My suspicion is now that the sed command is not executing at all.

Comment: Nemo, it was something to do with the carriage returns so thanks for pointing me in that direction!  I've been using notepad++ under windows to edit the script and when I viewed all the characters the carriage returns were coming up as `cr/lf` so I've changed them all using `VI` and the script now works as expected :)

Comment: dos format, @Nemo is smart. Next time u can convert the format, dos2unix or so

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion the issue sounds like it is a cygwin shell problem.
The issue is that shell scripts may not have \r\n line terminations - they need \n terminations. Earlier versions of cygwin behaved differently.
The relevant section from a Cygwin FAQ at http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html

```
Q: Mysterious errors in shell scripts, .bashrc, etc


    A: You may get mysterious messages when bash reads
    your .bashrc or .bash_profile, such as
        "\r command not found"
    (or similar).  When you get rid of empty lines, the
    complaints about "\r" disappears, but probably other
    errors remain.  What is going on?

    The answer may lie in the fact that a text file (also
    called ASCII file) can come in two formats:
    in DOS format or in UNIX format. 
    Most editors can automatically detect the formats
    and work properly in either format.
    In the DOS format, a new line is represented by two characters:
    CR (carriage return or ASCII code 13) and LF (line feed or ASCII code 15).
    In the UNIX format, a new line is represented by only
    one character, LF.  When your .bashrc file is read,
    bash thinks the extra character is the name of a command,
    hence the error message.

    In Cygwin or unix, you can convert a file INFILE in DOS format
    to a file OUTFILE in Unix format by calling:

        > tr -d '\15'  OUTFILE

    NOTE:
    If you now compare the number of characters in INFILE and OUTFILE,
    you will see that the latter has lost the correct
    number of characters (i.e., the number of lines in INFILE):

        > wc INFILE OUTFILE
```

Comment: Since I just linked this question / answer as a duplicate, I'd like to add that the `dos2unix` utility (available from Cygwin setup) provides a comfortable way to "kill" DOS carriage returns in a file, without having to go through `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using that instead:

```
sed -i -e "s/\<link\>/\n/g" /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rss.tmp
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to give an output file or the result will be only shown on the screen.

```
sed -e 's/<link>/\n/g' /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rss.tmp > /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/output.tmp
```

Answer (score -4):

to feed a file to the command you use "<", while to make a file u use ">" and sed is used as text formater not editor as far as i know
maybe something like this should work

```
cat < /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rss.tmp | sed -i -e "s/<link>/\n/g" > /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rssedit.tmp
```

cat gets the file and with sed editing it and ouput goes to rssedit.tmp

than check if rssedit.tmp has what u wanted

**if it does and only if it does**

next line of the your skript 
should be

```
mv /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rssedit.tmp /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rss.tmp
```

which will replace made 1 with original, with renameing to original

Comment: No, `sed -i` modifies the file in place. Jamie's problem was that the script had a CR at the end of the line, so `sed` was trying to access a file called `rss.tmpCR`.

Comment: glead he fixed it how ever what i wrote was cat < /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rss.tmp | sed -i -e "s/<link>/\n/g" > /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rssedit.tmp so that he can see if rssedit.tmp has changes he wants than he moves old file to new with mv /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rssedit.tmp /usb/lenny/rss/tmp/rss.tmp